# how to get latest modified files for different files in c#?

Tags: c#

my file names are

> 1. myfile_TCL.txt;
> 2. myfile_TCL_i1.txt;
> 3. myfile_TCL_i2.txt;
> 4. myfile_TCL_i3.txt;
> 5. testfile_TCL_i1.txt;
> 6. testfile_TCL_i2.txt;

my output should be "myfile_TCL_i3" and "testfile_TCL_i2" which are latest modified files for two different files.
Note:I may have so many number of different files and their modified files.

Comment: Please add some codes that your wrote. And please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking , http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could do it with a LINQ statement like this

```
var fi = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\temp");
var order = fi.GetFiles().OrderBy(x => x.LastWriteTime);
//or
var orderdesc  = fi.GetFiles().OrderByDescending (x => x.LastWriteTime);
```

edit 1

```
foreach (var file in order)
{
    Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);
}
```

Comment: Probably a good solution, but it's not clear from the problem whether those are the only files in the directory.

Comment: thank you..but i am getting all file names instead of latest modified files

Comment: files are in same folder

Comment: @SimonPrice - I think the op meant they just wanted to return the latest `myfile` and `testfile` file, but it shouldn't be too hard for them to modify your solution to do this.

Comment: @Simonprice -with your code i am getting all file names, but i need only latest modified files like 'myfile_TCL_i3" and "testfile_TCL_i3" as output

Comment: these are the files that are last modified, ordered in either direction.  if myfile_TCL_i3 and testfile_TCL_i3 are not modified one after the other then they will not be at the top of the list together. Are both files modified at the same time, or is one file modified and then you want to pick out both the myFile and the testFile?

Comment: @SimonPrice-they may be modified any time and new modified file will be produced as a result of modification (example:I open myFile_TCL_il3 and do some modifiacation and i do save as myFile_TCL_il4 in same directory), i want to pick out both the myFile(latest modified file) and testFile(latest modified) as output.

Comment: @SimonPrice  thank you..